# Wordpress Multisite - Auto enable theme

Tags: multisite, themes, network-admin

I have a server that uses themes from our private repository, and I'd like to auto enable the themes as soon as they exist in the wordpress themes folder.

Right now I have to login as administrator and enable the theme network-wide so the adminisrators can choose the theme.

Is there a way to configure wordpress network to AUTO enable the themes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. For something like that to work, WordPress (or some plugin to do that) would need to scan themes folder for changes, and that can be performance intensive operation. Maybe with some sort of scheduled scan running every few minutes.

I am not aware of any plugin that can do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding 3 new themes per week, you mean you just want them to be network activated automically? Use-WP-cli to install and activate them or deploy them from github.

Answer (score -1):

You can override the WordPress default theme by editing your wp-config.php file. Just add the following code anywhere before the line where WordPress includes the wp-settings.php file.

Add this

```
1:    define( 'WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'your-default-theme' );
```

Before

```
2:    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

So when you will create a new subsite in multisite, it will automatically enable the theme defined in WP-CONFIG file.

If theme is not availabe it will choose defauly twentyseventeen theme.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the question is more to ENABLE new themes automatically instead of setting the default site theme.

Comment: @Tzn, using WP_DEFAULT_THEME you can enable new theme automatically,

Comment: I add like 3 new themes a week, so I'd have to set each one in wp-settings for it to work and have it being default theme, which I don't want. I just want to enable it network-wide so the site administrators can pick them. Thanks for the help anyway.